# UserScopedSettingAttribute or ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, app-config

I'm implementing a new class library's settings and I'm wanting to use .NET 2.0's settings architecture, instead of the regular `appSettings` section in a `.config` file.

I've created a `Main.settings` file through the Visual Studio 2008 IDE, and this has autogenerated both the `Main.settings` file and a corresponding `Main.Designer.cs` file.  In the IDE, I have to select between whether each setting should have User scope or Application scope, which translates to the IDE applying either `UserScopedSettingAttribute` or `ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute` to the setting's Property.

The [stuff on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx) I've found on the topic seems to come at things from the point of view of a Windows Forms application; it talks about using user-scoped settings for stuff which pertains just to the user using the app, and application-scoped settings for stuff which always pertains to the app, no matter which user is using it.

However, what should I do when my settings file isn't for a Windows Forms app, but for a class library that I'm calling from a website under IIS?  Does it matter whether I scope the settings as User or Application?  If so, what factors are there to take into account as to how I should scope the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications do not support user scoped application settings. To get similar functionality, you could use the [SettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) class or create your own implementation of it. For application-wide settings, you will have to use the web.config file and either

1. Utilize the appSettings section and use [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) to access those settings, or
2. Implement your own [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx).

The answer to your second question is: it depends.

In a web app, user-scoped settings are usually associated with a session and allow for each user to have a different value for a particular setting. These settings are usually used to customize a user's experience.  On the other hand, if you want a setting to be the same application-wide regardless of the user who is accessing the application, you should be using an application-scoped setting.

If you provide more detail regarding your specific situation, I may be able to provide further guidance.

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743866/configuring-file-for-dlls) if you want to use a config file from the class library instead of placing your settings in the web.config file.